# Shinryu Battle at Low Level

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I've been neglecting to level Wakka and Tidus is only slightly better. Now I'm hacking through the Monster Arena and SURPRISE Shinryu is an underwater battle.

I can't seem to find any advice on dealing with Shinryu at a low level. Just [tons of advice to level up my characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30190191/2642059). I'm working on that now, but I was hoping that someone had some hints on how to deal with Shinryu without maxing Strength, Agility, Magic Defense, and Evasion, cause that's a long way off for me.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: No.**

Shinryu isn't a strong monster compared to most other mobs in the monster farm, but you have to fight it with tidus, wakka and rikku, if they aren't strong enough, there is almost no chance. Is has 2kk HP, magic is rather useless against it since it halves the dmg of all elements, resists most special conditions and got a few powerful attacks, including kicking 2 of your teammates out of the fight instantly, without chance to recover them, leaving you with a single person to fight it.

So don't even try it. It will cost you a lot of nerves and will most likely never be successful. The monster farm bosses weren't build for low level characters.

Comment: Is there a point you would concede fighting him before my stats are maxed?

Comment: No. The point is, he can knock 2 people out of the party. They are gone. You can't get them back. So, basically, he kicks 2 out, one is left. Then he will most likely kill you in 2 or 3 turns. The only way to beat shinryu is to kill him fast, preferably with wakkas 2nd limit. Otherwise, not even a maxed stat team can beat him.

Answer (score 0):

Shinryu is relatively weak except for his Eraser attack, which there is no blocking, it will always eliminate a character. *When* this happens however is random.

I just came back and tried to Quick Hit Shinryu to death and I won first try. My stats are nowhere near maxed *and* I lost Titus on Shinryu's first turn. I do have Celestial Weapons, but I did not perfect any of Wakka's Overdrive (though I did get Tidus's.)

Here are my stats:

Tidus:

- HP: 9999
- Strength: 142
- Defense: 94
- Magic: 56
- Magic Defense: 29
- MP: 572
- Agility: 98
- Luck: 20
- Evasion: 56
- Accuracy: 68

Wakka:

- HP: 9999
- Strength: 150
- Defense: 126
- Magic: 86
- Magic Defense: 75
- MP: 850
- Agility: 122
- Luck: 21
- Evasion: 89
- Accuracy: 81

Rikku:

- HP: 9999
- Strength: 99
- Defense: 119
- Magic: 116
- Magic Defense: 116
- MP: 999
- Agility: 142
- Luck: 26
- Evasion: 104
- Accuracy: 45

All this to say I believe that this could be done with significantly lower stats. If Wakka got a successful overdrive and if Sinryu did not use Eraser right off the bat, of course that may take several attempts to achieve. I'd love to hear if someone has accomplished this at an even lower level!